# Configure ILSpy to show details behind generated code for local method

Tags: .net, ilspy

I trying to see compiler's code for this little sample:

```
static void Main()
{
    int i = 0;
    AddToI(5);
    AddToI(10);
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    void AddToI(int amount) => i += amount;
}
```

I am using ILSpy and it is showing me code almost identical to the original.
But I expected compiler to add some class or structure?

Maybe I can tune ILSpy to show me more details?

Comment: It was the goal of the ILSpy authors to make the output resemble C# as close as possible.  If you want to see the soul of the machine then consider using ildasm.exe, run it from the Developer Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a lower language version (e.g. C# 6) in the toolbar to prevent ILSpy from using newer features.

You also can turn off individual language features in View>Options>Decompiler.

To quickly see "what does this code compile to?", you can use https://sharplab.io.
SharpLab's C# mode also uses the ILSpy decompiler, but with almost all features disabled.

Comment: SharpLab is really cool - it did show me right away what I wanted (compiler generated class). I almost managed to get same result using ILSpy: I deselected "Introduce local functions". But it still does not show me compiler generated class itself. Maybe you know how to fix that?

Comment: You can enable View > Show all types and members.